# Auto-renewable subscription with in-app purchases hosted content

Tags: ios, subscription, storekit, newsstand-kit, auto-renewing

I'm testing auto-renewable subscription in Newsstand app, and subscription works well, I have purchase and expiration date. But I don't understand hot to get access to in-app purchases hosted content or how to buy issue without charging payment? Should I copy my issues to my own server?

I read a lot of tutorials and In-App Purchase Programming Guide and I can't figure out. Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate this point "But I don't understand hot to get access to in-app purchases hosted content or how to buy issue without charging payment?" in deep

Comment: When I buy issue from in-app purchase I have SKPaymentTransaction and I can download issue, but when subscription is active I should have access to issue. How to download issue without my own server?

Comment: I think its Simple, just do restore purchase and you will get all your purchased issues.

Comment: For example, I purchased Issue1, then I purchased auto-renewable subscription. When I restore purchases I will get 2 SKPaymentTransaction (Issue1 and auto-renewable subscription), I don't get SKPaymentTransaction for Issue2.

Comment: You purchased Issue1 and subscription so there are only two payment transactions that is fine. So how can you get Issue2 that you never purchased? of course you will only get those two payment transaction only.

Comment: Yes, Issue2 should be available because subscription is active.

Comment: Yes Then you maintain your server side called API (web service). After successfully purchased subscription, you need to call web service and maintain the database that user has already purchase these these issues. So when user click on Restore purchase, after successfully restore purchased again call your web service to know how many issues are purchased already. That's it.

Comment: if you satisfied with my comments then let me know then I write this comment in answer so you will may accept it. thanks

Comment: I think that for now it is not impossible, because when my issues will be on my server it's no sense to duplicate it on apple servers. Maybe in future it will be available.

Comment: so can I give you answer properly as my last comment? so I write my answer and you will may accept it so other Questioner also see this question and answer.